# Считать с клавиатуры строку и разбить ее на отдельные слова

Tags: java

Под словом подразумевается набор символов, ограниченный пробелами и знаками
препинания.

Помогите решить

Answer (score 1):

Можно например так

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.next();
```

UPDATE:

```
String[] words = s.split("\W");
```

Comment: а дальше: String[] strings = s.split(" ");

Comment: в стороке нет пробелов, split не подойдет

Comment: s.split("[., ]") подойдет?

Comment: str.split("(?<=\\G.{6})", 6); вот так работает